# How do I get the value from an attribute after onclick event?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have an `a` tag with an `onclick` event:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="{!c.handleClick}" data="{!a.Id}"
```

And a JavaScript controller method to handle it:

```
handleClick: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    let el = event.target;
    console.log(el.data);
},
```

How do I get the value in the `data` attribute?

Comment: Is data supposed to be a custom html attribute? If so, shouldnt it be data-something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a data attribute, such as:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="{!c.handleClick}" data-record-id="{!a.Id}"
```

Which you then access via [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

```
var recordId = event.currentTarget.dataset.recordId;
```